# How do I copy all the files containing "t_1" in the name to a different directory using one command?

Tags: files, wildcards, cp

How do I copy all the files with "t_1" in the name to a different directory using one command?

Comment: `cp "*t_1*" /target/dir/`...

Comment: @jasonwryan it is saying "cp: cannot stat ‘*t_1*’: No such file or directory"

Comment: Are you in a directory that includes at least one file with `t_1` in the name?

Comment: Yes because I can do ls | grep "t_1" and files show up. There are 4.

Comment: Remove the quotes: `*t_1*`...

Comment: @jasonwryan FINALLY YES THANK YOU SO MUCH I LOVE YOU <3

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
cp /path/to/files/*t_1* /path/to/destination
```

or just

```
cp ./*t_1* /path/to/destination
```

if the files are in the current directory.

Or,

```
for f in ./*t_1*; do
    cp "$f" /path/to/destination
done
```

That should work for sure, even if there are many thousands of files matching the pattern in the current directory.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a quick fix..

```
find ./ -name '*t_1*' -exec mv '{}' ./ \;
```

This code will move all the files (containing the search pattern in the file name) one level up the hierarchy.

For example, Let's say that all your 't_1'  files are stored in **/Home/Desktop/** directory. Then just go to **/Home/** from terminal and execute this command. All the 't_1' files will be moved from **/home/Desktop/** to **/home/** directory.

All the files irrespective of the position of t_1 in the filename will be copied.

Comment: just copy the command as it is....presence or absence of a whitespace will affect the results. I have tried and tested this command before posting this answer

Comment: once you have all your files in the parent folder, you can move the entire parent folder wherever you wish

Comment: This would copy all the files matching the pattern in the current directory or below, to the current directory, not just from one level below the current directory.